# Match java.sql.Timestamp with DB2 Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, groovy, timestamp, db2

I need to pass Timestamp value as parameter in URL to retrieve some data.
Format of Timestamp in DB2 is: 2022-05-25-11:10:44.662000, but in java.sql.Timestamp is: 2022-05-25 11:10:44.0
and when I pass it, it returns empty list.

My ActionController class method:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/fetchData/{id}/{timestamp}")
  def fetchData(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable Timestamp timestamp) {
    def serviceResult = actionService.fetchData(id, timestamp);
    return parseServiceResult(serviceResult)
  }
```

My ActionService class method:

```
  ServiceResult fetchData(int id, Timestamp timestamp) {
    ServiceResult ret = new ServiceResult()
    List<DataDTO> retSet = new ArrayList<DataDTO>()
    List<String> errorMessage = new ArrayList<String>()
    try {
      retSet = actionEntity.fetchData(id, timestamp)
    } catch (CollectionsException e) {
      errorMessage << "ActionService.fetchData error"
      log.debug("ActionService.fetchData error" + e.getMessage())
    }
    ret = new ServiceResult(success: errorMessage.isEmpty(), result: retSet, errorMessageTextList: errorMessage)

    ret
  }
```

My ActionEntity class method:

```
ArrayList<DataDTO> fetchPoulsFromStorno(int id, Timestamp timestamp) throws CollectionsException {

    def sql = """SELECT * FROM NSNP.TABLE1 PT INNER JOIN NSNP.TABLE2 ST
                        ON (ST.COLUMN1 = PT.COLUMN1 AND
                        ST.COLUMN2 = PT.COLUMN2 AND
                        ST.COLUMN3 = PT.COLUMN3 AND
                        ST.COLUMN4 = PT.COLUMN4 AND
                        ST.COLUMN5 = PT.COLUMN5 AND
                        ST.COLUMN6 = PT.COLUMN6 AND
                        ST.COLUMN7 = PT.COLUMN7 AND
                        ST.COLUMN8 = PT.COLUMN8 )
                        WHERE ST.ID = $id AND ST.TIMESTAMP= $timestamp"""


    ArrayList<DataDTO> dataList = new ArrayList<DataDTO>()

    try {
      if (this.sql != null) {
        this.sql.eachRow(sql) {
          resultSet ->
            System.out.println(resultSet)
            DataDTO dataDTO = new DataDTO()
            dataDTO .setProperty1(resultSet.COLUMN1)
            dataDTO .setPropety2(resultSet.COLUMN2)
            dataDTO .setProperty3(resultSet.COLUMN3)
            
            dataList.add(dataDTO)
        }
      }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
      log.info "ActionEntity.fetchData error $se.message  executed sql: $sql"
    } finally {
      if (this.sql != null) {
        this.sql.close()
      }
    }
    dataList
  }
```

Can't provide you exact and real data, but I'm sure you'll understand code and what I'm trying to do.

Comment: *WHERE ST.ID = $id AND ST.TIMESTAMP= $timestamp"""* You're *really* going to feed in the correct value somehow, down to nanosecond accuracy to get results?

Comment: I need to check timestamp from database. Is there a way to check it without providing correct value, down to nanosecond accuracy, because I don't know will I pass it to nanoseconds?

Comment: You probably need to query within a range, not an exact value. Or truncate the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are using the wrong types.

- To exchange data with a DB2 column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.LocalDateTime`.
- To exchange data with a DB2 column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

Never use the flawed legacy class `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Your hour difference is likely resulting from that class adjusting for time zone, which is problematic because the `TIMESTAMP` column (`TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column) in DB2 has no time zone or offset.

## Details

> Format of Timestamp in DB2 is: 2022-05-25-11:10:44.662000

No, a [`TIMESTAMP`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=values-timestamp) type in DB2 does not have a format. That type does not contain text. That type uses its own internally-defined data for tracking a date-time value.

The matching type in Java for a DB2 column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

> but in java.sql.Timestamp

Never use the `Timestamp` class. That class is part of the legacy date-time classes that were tragically flawed in their design. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. The `Timestamp` class was specifically replaced by `java.time.Instant`, though for interacting with a database you would use `OffsetDateTime` class.

JDBC 4.2 and later requires all JDBC drivers to support an appropriate subset of the *java.time* classes.

## Moment versus not-a-moment

Another issue is that `TIMESTAMP` in DB2 (short for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`) purposely lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or time zone. Without an offset or zone, that type cannot be used to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

In contrast, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class *does* represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

So `TIMESTAMP` in DB2 does not match up to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Instead, for exchanging values with a `TIMESTAMP` column in DB2, use the `java.time.LocalDateTime` class. Like the DB2 type, that class purposely lacks the context of an offset or zone.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-05-25T11:10:44.662000" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/pvzClV).

> ldt.toString() is 2022-05-25T11:10:44.662

Writing.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Resolution

The `TIMESTAMP` type in DB2 resolves to the very FINE resolution of picoseconds. To quote the manual:

> The number of digits in the fractional seconds portion is specified using an attribute in the range 0 - 12 with a default of 6

A [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), a billionth of a second, is a fractional second of nine digits. Twelve digits represent a [picosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picosecond), a trillionth of a second.

The *java.time* classes have a resolution of nanoseconds.